# Updated xcode 5.0 to xcode 5.1.1 facing illegal Configuration while compiling

Tags: ios, objective-c

Updated xcode 5.0 to 5.1.1 getting illegal confinguration static table views are only valid when ebedded in UITableviewcontroller instances

Comment: Why are you still using older versions when 6.1.1 is out?

Comment: Even i am getting the same issue with 6.1 while compiling the project which is developed below 5.0 version.